# Get data from internet in Android

Tags: android, html-parsing

I want to get content from my internet site and show these content in listview and text view. I used the jsoup library for parsing HTML, but my app is using 25 MB ram which as you know is quite a lot for an app.

How can I improve the ram efficiency of my application?

Answer (score 3):

You could display it with a webview, instead of trying to parse it and convert it into a native view.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         //.. Other setup ...   
         //Add webview     
         WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
         myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
         myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JSBridge(), "JSJavaBridge");
         myWebView.loadUrl("http://my.testdomain.com/theSharedPage.html"); 
    }
```

Then write methods in JSBridge class to handle any interactions between JS and Java.  For example:

```
private class JSBridge
{ 
    public playSound(){
         mp = MediaPlayer.create(Test.this, R.raw.mysound);   
         mp.start();
    }
}
```

Then in HTML, use the JSBridge to play a sound from Java.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $( '#playSound' ).click(function () {

                    if(typeof JSJavaBridge != 'undefined')
                          JSJavaBridge.playSound();
                });
            });
    </script>
```

Comment: No i dont want this because of my site isn't appropriate for mobile phones.so i have to get strings from internet and edit it as i wanted.

Comment: Ideally you would rewrite the site/page to use modern responsive design techniques to get it to adjust to the the mobile device.  Using page scraping, as you suggest, is a maintenance nightmare.  But if you see no other way, then you can actually use a WebView with a string. You could download the page, modified it in code, then load the string in a WebView.  
*String str = "<html><body>FOO</body></html>"; 
webview.loadData(str, "text/html", null);*
  Good Luck, how ever you end up going.

Comment: I can't see no other way so which parser i have to use?Also i have bitmaps in listview.How can i improve ram effiency about bitmaps?